# changing date format with posixct in r

Tags: r, date, time, posixct

I have a list of dates in two formats. 
the first one: 8/1/2014 0:03:00
the second one: 2014-09-01 00:01:00
from two different datasets.

When I try to convert the first one to posixct in works great using:

```
df$Date.Time=as.POSIXct(df$Date.Time,tz="America/New_York"
,format = "%m/%d/%Y%H:%M:%S")
```

but when I try to convert the other one - it converts everything to NA's. I use the same code as before.

Would appreciate a tip on what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formats you want to convert are different. You have to change the format argument to what your data looks like. 8/1/2014 0:03:00 require format = "%m/%d/%Y%H:%M:%S". The second one 2014-09-01 00:01:00 requires format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S".

```
t<-"2014-09-01 00:01:00"

test <- as.POSIXct(t,tz="America/New_York",
format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to state a format for the second type, because that's the default format as.POSIXct expects: `as.POSIXct(t)
[1] "2014-09-01 00:01:00 EDT"`